# Calculating the golden ratio iteratively

Tags: c, math

[image]

This is the sequence defined by a0 = 1 and a(n+1) = sqrt(1 + an), I'm trying to calculate it's first 40 terms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    float limit = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {

        limit = 1 + sqrt(limit);
        printf("%1.21f\n", limit);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Output

```
2.000000000000000000000
2.414213657379150390625
2.553774118423461914062
2.598053216934204101562
2.611847877502441406250
2.616121292114257812500
2.617442846298217773438
2.617851257324218750000
2.617977619171142578125
....
```

My code is giving me `the true value + 1`. I can subtract 1 from the final answer, but I feel like it's ugly code.

Comment: I think you have used the wrong equation,
it is : limit = sqrt(1+limit);

Comment: R u mean sqrt(xn)==sqrt(x*n)..?

Comment: I think it is `G(n+1) = 1 + 1 / G(N)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are expecting for this..

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main ()
 {
 float limit = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++ ) {

    limit =sqrt( 1 + limit);//changes here
    printf("%1.21f\n", limit);
 }

 return(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your iterative sequence is wrong.

```
X(n+1) = 1 + sqrt(X(n))

(X(n+1) - 1)^2 = X(n)
(X(n+1))^2 - 2X(n+1) - X(n) + 1 = 0
```

Let `lim n->inf X(n) = L`, then

```
L^2 - 3L + 1 = 0
```

So L is `(3+sqrt(5))/2` (positive number) and it is bigger than golden ratio, which is `(1+sqrt(5))/2`.